# How to get hardware information(hdd serial number,cpu id,network physical address etc.) using wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, wxformbuilder

I am using wxWidgets in wxFormBuilder platform.(Microsoft Visual Studio C++)

I want to get hardware information(hdd serial number,cpu id,network physical address etc). How can I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: For a licence manager software

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to retrieve most of this information using wxWidgets API.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of settings that can be read with [wxSystemSettings](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_system_settings.html). Here is the [list of what settings](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/settings_8h.html) that can be read.